# Suggestions for an overview of testing for developers (online only)

Tags: training

My company is taking a new approach to onboarding entry level developers which includes some QA/Software testing training.  I've been trying to find some training specifically for developers, but have only been able to find intensive testing courses for people that are already a tester or people who want to change careers.

The company is fully remote, so it has to be something online so that everyone can access it easily.

Comment: "My company is taking a new approach to onboarding entry level developers which includes some QA/Software testing training. " - why? What is the goal?

Answer (score -1):

Three places I suggest good courses are [Ministry of Testing](https://www.ministryoftesting.com/essentials/training),[Rapid Software Testing](https://rapid-software-testing.com/attending-rst/), and the [Association for Software Testing](https://associationforsoftwaretesting.org/bbst-black-box-software-testing-courses/).

And although it's not directly about the testing craft, [Dave Farley's courses](https://www.continuous-delivery.co.uk/learning) can be good as well.

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  I'll check them out

Comment: @Brandy You are welcome. If you found the answer satisfactory, could you mark it as Accepted, so other will see the value in it?